# Loading different paragraphs when the user clicks on image's bullet

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have an image with bullets on it and i want when a bullet is clicked the paragraph next to the image to change but not to reload the whole page, just the certain paragraph. I know that this can be done with ajax call, but i believe i could use some hints.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with js and ajax. When you click on the image, pass the position to the server side (which bullet has pushed) , and use `.html()` function for your paragraph.

Comment: thanks for the advice, is there any example like this already made in order to give it a look?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/ check the jsFiddle to see the result.

Comment: that seems helpfull enough i ll read it and give it a try.

Comment: I have done that so lolka_bolka write your solution in order to confirm it, thank you again.